# How many runs of an Azure Logic App can occur at the same time?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm having trouble figuring this out, I'm looking at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=consumption%2Cazure-portal

I have a Consumption logic app. It is using a service bus trigger to run, set up to run any time a message is received in a queue, checking every 10 seconds.

If I send 2,000 messages to the queue, will it process all the messages at the same time, with the logic app doing 2,000 runs concurrently? Or is there a limit, and it will only process 250, wait, grab 250 more, wait, etc?

Answer (score 0):

When using a Service Bus trigger in a Consumption plan Logic App, the trigger polls the Service Bus queue or topic subscription for new messages at a regular interval (default is every 10 seconds). When a new message is detected, the Logic App instance is created to process that message.

In your scenario, if you send 2,000 messages to the queue, the Service Bus trigger will detect each message and create a new instance of the Logic App to process it. However, the number of instances that can run concurrently is limited by the maximum number of concurrent executions allowed for the Consumption plan.

For example, if the maximum number of concurrent executions is 50. This means that the Logic App will process up to 50 messages concurrently. If there are more than 50 messages in the queue, the remaining messages will be processed as soon as one of the existing instances completes.

If you need to process more messages concurrently, you can consider scaling up to a higher tier plan or using a different trigger that supports higher concurrency, such as the Event Grid trigger.

Refer doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#change-trigger-concurrency